# OOP and AJAX form submission issues

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After submitting my form below via ajax the message always comes back as failed, even with the correct login information! I've coded this in a non oop style too and it works perfectly, but when i use this style of code it hangs up. The live site is http://andyholmes.me/demo/summersproperty/OOP/login.php and the username is admin@summersproperty.com and password is admin

login.php -

```
    <?PHP
session_start();

include('includes/class.login.php');

$login = new Login();


$token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

if ($_POST['ajax']) {
    exit($login->getStatus());
}

?>
<style>
    #message { display: none; cursor: pointer; }
    .loader { display: none; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
        $(this).fadeOut(300);
        $('.loader').delay(300).fadeIn(100);
        $.post("<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>", { username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val(), ajax: true }).done(function(data) {
            if (data.logged_in == true) {
                // Redirect with javascript
                $('.loader').delay(2000).fadeOut(100);
                $('#message').html('<p>Success! We\'ll redirect you in a minute...</p>').delay(2200).fadeIn(200);
            } else {
                $('.loader').delay(2000).fadeOut(100);
                $('#message').html('<p>Failed... Click to try again!').delay(2200).fadeIn(200);
                $('#message').on('click', function(){
                    $(this).fadeOut(200);
                    $('#loginForm').delay(350).fadeIn(200);
                });
            }
        }); 
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$token;?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In"/>
</form>
<div class="loader">
    <img src="loader.gif"/>
</div>
<div id="message"></div>
```

and the login class -

```
<?PHP

class Login 
{
    private $_id;
    private $_username;
    private $_password;
    private $_passmd5;

    private $_errors;
    private $_access;
    private $_login;
    private $_token;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_errors = array();
        $this->_login  = isset($_POST['login']) ? 1 : 0;
        $this->_access = 0;
        $this->_token  = $_POST['token'];

        $this->_id     = 0;
        $this->_username = ($this->_login) ? $this->filter($_POST['username']) : $_SESSION['username'];
        $this->_password = ($this->_login) ? $this->filter($_POST['password']) : '';
        $this->_passmd5  = ($this->_login) ? md5($this->_password) : $_SESSION['password'];

    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        ($this->_login) ? $this->verifyPost() : $this->verifySession();

        return $this->_access;
    }

    public function filter($var)
    {
        return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/','',$var);
    }

    public function verifyPost()
    {
        try
        {
            if(!$this->isTokenValid())
                throw new Exception('Invalid form submission');

            if(!$this->isDataValid())
                throw new Exception('Invalid form data entered');

            if(!$this->verifyDatabase())
                throw new Exception('Invalid username/password combination');

        $this->_access = 1;
        $this->registerSession();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $this->_errors[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function verifySession()
    {
        if($this->sessionExist() && $this->verifyDatabase())
            $this->_access = 1;
    }

    public function verifyDatabase()
    {
        include('dbConfig.php');

        $data = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_username = '{$this->_username}' AND user_password = '{$this->_passmd5}'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($data))
        {
            list($this->_id) = @array_values(mysql_fetch_assoc($data));
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function isDataValid()
    {
        return (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/', $this->_username) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/', $this->_password)) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public function isTokenValid()
    {
        return (!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $this->_token != $_SESSION['token']) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public function registerSession()
    {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $this->_id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $this->_username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $this->_passmd5;
    }

    public function sessionExist()
    {
        return (isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public function showErrors()
    {
        echo "<h3>Errors</h3>";
        foreach($this->_errors as $key=>$value)
            echo $value."<br>";
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
    return json_encode(array('logged_in' => $this->isLoggedIn(), 'errors' => $this->showErrors()));
    }   
}

?>
```

By the way, i know i need to use PDOs etc, but i just want to get the script to a point where it works nicely before i change the database connection data. I know im close, but its really frustrating!

If you can help me, i will be most grateful!

EDIT NOTES: This code has been updated for an issue that has come up after using the suggestion from user1781670

Comment: Not everything that uses a class is oop :-)

Comment: Okay... Not really the issue i'm having though! haha

Comment: PHP is a server side language executed at server, not at client. So, your php code in $.post callback function will be executed before any ajax request will be send

Comment: Oh yeah i know :) This is the bit i'm struggling on. Of course you can see all my errors are being handled via the class, what would you suggest?

Comment: Have your HTML (form) on one page and your PHP code on another (a processing page). Send the AJAX request to your processing page.

Comment: Thanks, i sort of assumed that before but wasn't sure if i'd be able to still use my class verifying stuff. I'll give it a shot

Comment: I suggest you to do like @pmandell said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?PHP
session_start();


include('includes/class.login.php');

$login = new Login();


$token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

if ($_POST['ajax']) {
    exit($login->getStatus());
}

?>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
        $.post("<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>", { username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val(), ajax: true }).done(function(data) {
            if (data.logged_in == true) {
                // Redirect with javascript
            } else {
                // Inject errors to html
                // data.errors
            }
        }); 
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$token;?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In"/>
</form>
```

As you can see I modified your jquery removing you PHP code inside because that's not the place where it goes, also I changed the syntax a little to one more clear at least for me. Also note that "data" is a json returned by your PHP function getStatus who returns the login status as json.

Now you just need to create the PHP function that return the json. Maybe can help you to checkout [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). If you get stuck please tell us.

Example of getStatus function:

JavaScript objects are like associate arrays in PHP except JavaScript objects can have functions. So, is not surprise you need to pass an associative array to json_encode.

```
public function getStatus()
{
    return json_encode(array('logged_in' => $this->isLoggedIn(), 'errors' => $this->showErrors()));
}
```

$.post automatically knows it received a JSON (it's the default option), so you can access it's properties with data.logged_in and data.errors.

This is the problem: you show your login form and when the user submit the form, through ajax you open a connection and send the data entered by the user and you expect the server to return information. But how is that data gonna be returned? how are you gonna handle it? well, that is JSON for. It's a syntax to write JavaScript objects, so with json_encode you return a JSON and when your JavaScript receives that JSON you can access it's data and check if it was a successful login.

Comment: so getStatus is the function i need to create for errors etc? I'm assuming i can't use all the error/data handling previously created in my class file?

Comment: Yes you can, that's the idea. JSON it's a way to write javascript objects, following that idea you can pass all your PHP object status to your javascript code. One example is: { logged_in: false, errors: ['username can\'t be blank', 'password can\'t be blank'] }. From your javascript you can access those attributes like data.logged_in & data.errors.

Comment: As you can tell im pretty fresh to this! Definitely need help haha

Comment: I don't quite follow how to get this JSON thing to work with a new function called getStatus

Comment: Haha no problem, you are doing well. Try to advance as far as you can and if get stucked bring the questions ;)

Comment: I'm just really confused. I have my login class which handled all the data as it should before i decided the AJAX way and it was perfect. Now i just need it to either display the associated errors depending on the data received in the class file or redirect. Im sorry, i really don't understand how to sort this :P

Comment: Do you have an example that would help explain how to put the two together at all? I do apologise for my lack of knowledge, this is the best way i learn believe it or not! haha

Comment: Hey I'm back, see my updated answer and let me know if you need more help.

Comment: This works really well. Now the ONLY issue im having is no matter what i'm typing in i always get a failed message. ATM i'm testing it with jquery changing the html of a div to display success or fail, and even with the right info it's just failing :(

Comment: Have updated the code for you mate. Marking your answer as the correct one as despite my issues now, its working and i am incredibly grateful!

Comment: I got it sorted in the end, thanks so much for everything. Really appreciate it

Comment: Here comes in handy google chrome web developer tools. Open the panel with cmd + option + I on mac and click on the network tab. Scroll down until the end and try to login, should appear a new connection. Open this new connection and click on the response tab to see what responded the server.
Ninja edit: Oh! didn't see you got it working. You're welcome! glad I could help.